# Translation of "dynamic" content if using Internationalization with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization, translation

I am currently evaluating the C++ framework [Qt](http://qt.io) v5.4.1. Currently I am
trying to understand and apply [Internationalization with Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/internationalization.html).

I successfully implemented switching of the human language at runtime via the
help of the article [How to create a multi lingual application that can switch
the language at runtime?](https://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application) and I know how-to work with Qt Linguist Translation
source (.ts) files and how to generate Qt Linguist Message (.qm) files. I use
the build system [CMake](http://cmake.org) to automate the generation and it works very nice.

In my project the translations are loaded from a Qt Resource Collection (.qrc)
file compiled into the application. I know how-to translate "static" strings via
the member functions [`QObject::tr()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#tr) and [`QObject::translate()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#translate).

Now comes the tricky part: I want to add languages while my application evolves.
Currently I have the following two .ts files:

- `foo_ui_de_DE.ts`
- `foo_ui_en_US.ts`

These are compiled via `lrelease` into the following two .qm files by the build
process:

- `foo_ui_de_DE.qm`
- `foo_ui_en_US.qm`

The build process automatically generates a .qrc file `translations.qrc` and
compiles that file into the executable via `rcc`.

Relevant source code from the declaration file (.h):

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLocale>
#include <QString>
#include <QTranslator>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  /**
   * Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class with the given parent.
   *
   * @param parent The parent.
   */
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget* parent = 0);

 private slots:
  /**
   * Loads a language by the given language shortcut (e.g. `de_DE`, `en_US`).
   */
  void LoadLanguage(QLocale const& kLocale);

  void SwitchTranslator(QTranslator& translator,
                        QString const& kLocale,
                        QString const& kFilename);

  /**
   * Creates the language menu dynamically.
   */
  void CreateLanguageMenu();

 protected:
  /**
   * Handler which is activated when a new translator is loaded or the system
   * language is changed.
   */
  void changeEvent(QEvent* event);

 protected slots:
  /**
   * Slot which is called by the language menu actions.
   */
  void slotLanguageChanged(QAction* action);

 private:
  /**
   * The translations for this application.
   */
  QTranslator translator_;

  /**
   * The translations for the Qt Widgets used in this application.
   */
  QTranslator qt_translator_;

  /**
   * Contains the currently loaded locale.
   */
  QLocale locale_;

  /**
   * The main window of the application.
   */
  Ui::MainWindow* ui_;
};
```

Relevant source code from the definition file (.cc):

```
#include <QLibraryInfo>

#include "main_window.h"

#include "ui_main_window.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* the_parent)
    : QMainWindow{the_parent},
      ui_{new Ui::MainWindow} {
  ui_->setupUi(this);
  CreateLanguageMenu();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
  delete ui_;
}

void MainWindow::LoadLanguage(QLocale const& kNewLocale) {
  QLocale::setDefault(kNewLocale);
  QString const kLanguageName{QLocale::languageToString(kNewLocale.language())};

  SwitchTranslator(translator_, "qt_" + kNewLocale.bcp47Name(),
                   QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
  SwitchTranslator(qt_translator_,
                   qApp->applicationName() + '_' + kNewLocale.name(),
                   ":/translations");
  statusBar()->showMessage(
      tr("Language changed to %1").arg(kLanguageName));
  locale_ = kNewLocale;
}

void MainWindow::SwitchTranslator(QTranslator& translator,
                                  QString const& kLocale,
                                  QString const& kFilename) {
  qApp->removeTranslator(&translator);

  if (translator.load(kLocale, kFilename)) {
    qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
  }
}

void MainWindow::CreateLanguageMenu() {
  // TODO(wolters): This is not optimal, since it does not work automatically
  // with the .qm files added as a resource to the application.
  //: Translation for the human language German.
  QT_TR_NOOP("German");
  //: Translation for the human language English.
  QT_TR_NOOP("English");

  QActionGroup* language_group{new QActionGroup(ui_->menuLanguage)};
  language_group->setExclusive(true);

  connect(language_group, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), this,
          SLOT(slotLanguageChanged(QAction*)));

  QLocale const kDefaultLocale{QLocale::system()};
  QDir const kDirectory{QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/.."};
  QStringList const kFileNames{kDirectory.entryList(QStringList("*.qm"))};

  for (QString const& kFileName : kFileNames) {
    QLocale const kLocale{QFileInfo{kFileName}.completeBaseName().replace(
        qApp->applicationName() + "_", "")};
    QString const kCountryCode{
        kLocale.name().toLower().mid(kLocale.name().lastIndexOf('_') + 1)};
    QIcon const kIcon{":/icons/flags/" + kCountryCode + ".png"};
    QAction* action{new QAction{
        kIcon,
        // TODO(wolters): This does not work.
        tr(QLocale::languageToString(kLocale.language()).toStdString().c_str()),
        this}};
    action->setCheckable(true);
    action->setData(kLocale);

    ui_->menuLanguage->addAction(action);
    language_group->addAction(action);

    if (kDefaultLocale == kLocale) {
      action->setChecked(true);
    }
  }
}

void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent* the_event) {
  if (nullptr != the_event) {
    switch (the_event->type()) {
      // QEvent::LanguageChange is send if a translator is loaded.
      case QEvent::LanguageChange:
        ui_->retranslateUi(this);
        break;
      // QEvent::LocaleChange is send, if the system language changes.
      case QEvent::LocaleChange:
        LoadLanguage(QLocale::system());
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  QMainWindow::changeEvent(the_event);
}

void MainWindow::slotLanguageChanged(QAction* action) {
  if (nullptr != action) {
    LoadLanguage(qvariant_cast<QLocale>(action->data()));
  }
}
```

The source code already describes the problem I have in the comments.

1. If the application is started, the current system locale is used to
   re-translate the UI. This works and I can see that the items in the menu
   `Languages` appear in the German human language (I've translated both items
   in the .ts files). But when I switch the language via the menu from German to
   English, both item labels **do not** get translated.
2. The approach is in general not optimal, since I do not want to modify the
   source code (`QT_TR_NOOP` above), if a new human language is added to the
   application. The optimal work flow would be:

   1. Add all supported languages to all .ts files in their proper language.
   2. Dynamically translate the menu items.

I think I am misunderstanding something, but I couldn't found a solution while
searching the WWW for a while.

**Update 2015-04-01:** I think I use the wrong approach. The important part is that the *Languages* menu is created dynamically in the member function `CreateLanguageMenu()`. I need an answer to the question how-to translate the dynamically created menu items. So it's all about the line `QAction* action{new QAction{kIcon, tr(QLocale::languageToString(kLocale.language()).toStdString().c_str()), this}};` in that function. I need some kind of lookup-functionality available at compile time I think...

Comment: How do you switch the language? Post the code.

Comment: I've added all relevant code to the question.

Comment: Where `translator_` and `qt_translator_` are coming from? Also, it would be great if you make a self-contained compilable example.

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevant source code from the header file. `translator_` and `qt_translator_` are declared there. But I don't think that's even relevant. I've clarified the problem in the question a bit. I cannot provide a full example at the moment. Maybe I can do it in eight hours.

Comment: Just an aside - I feel uncomfortable when I see `":/icons/flags/" + kCountryCode + ".png"`, because there's nothing like a one-to-one correspondence between countries and languages.  There's plenty of insightful reading to be found online on this topic, so I won't elaborate further in this short comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned you need a lookup-functionality but in real time.
I suggest such hack:
when creating QAction objects use object name as Language identifer

```
QT_TR_NOOP("LANG_ENG")
QAction* langAction = ...;
langAction->setObjectName("LANG_ENG");
```

on Language Change event call some method to retreanslate this actions

```
void retranslateLangActions()
{
    QList<QAction*> widgetActions = this->findChildren<QAction*>();
    foreach(QAction* act, widgetActions) // qt foreach macro
    {
        QString objName = act->objectName();
        if (objName.startsWith("LANG_"))
        {
            act->setText(tr(objName.toStdString().c_str()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is indeed a workaround, but not the final solution. I see one major problem: It does not allow to automatically add translations for menu items if new .qm files are added, since a new `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP` has to be added to the application. But I don't see a way to avoid that, maybe I should move the `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP` macro calls to a separate .h file and generate that file via the build system. Also, why isn't it possible to find all actions via `ui_->menuLanguage->->findChildren<QAction*>()`? If that would be possible, I could get rid of that ugly prefix.

Comment: One note to your code: It must be `for (QAction* act : findChildren<QAction*>()) {` and `act->setText(tr(objName.toStdString().c_str()));`

Comment: @Florian Wolters this is kind of a pseudo code... so if you want c++ i'll fix it a bit. ui_->menuLanguage->->findChildren<QAction*>() will work if you set  ui_->menuLanguage as parrent in ctor

Comment: The last argument of QAction Ctor is a parrent and you put there a MianWindow ptr (this). So my code is based on yours.

Comment: Just to clarify for others, @Ruslan F. means the constructor of `QAction`. I made a mistake while creating the `QAction` objects, since the last argument was `this`. Instead `language_group` should be used, then `ui_>menuLanguage->->findChildren<QAction*>()` works.

Comment: I've made it work without using `QAction::objectName()` and with dynamic generation of a header file which declares all required dynamic translations in a free function. The header is included in my `main.cc` and the free function is called. It works and I do not need to modify the source code if adding a new language, but it feels like a hack for sure! So I am open for a cleaner solution. But at the moment it is *Good Enough* (TM).